# Eisenstein series for quadratic number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, eisenstein-series

I am familiar with the theory of modular forms and weight k Eisenstein series, and I am wondering if such a theory exists when the base field is not $\mathbb{Z}$.

Is there a theory of modular forms over $SL_2(\mathcal{O_k})$ where $k$ is a real or imaginary quadratic number field? Moreover, is there a nice Fourier series expansion of their Eisenstein series (if they exist)? Please provide references.

Comment: It's hard to guess what you exactly need, but your best bet would be automorphic forms for $\mathrm{GL}_2(k)$. There is an Eisenstein series attached to a function in a Borel-induced representation, and it has a Fourier expansion. All these are explained in Bump, Automorphic Forms and Representations, section III.7 (but you probably need to read previous sections as well).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When $k$ is a real quadratic field (or more generally a totally real number field) the short answer is Hilbert modular forms. The corresponding Eisenstein series are called Hecke-Eisenstein series and are quite easily defined,
and yes they have a very nice Fourier expansion. For instance, this is what allowed Siegel to show that $\zeta_K(1-k)$ is always a rational number for
$k\ge2$.

The case of imaginary quadratic fields is a little more complicated: the modular forms are here called Bianchi modular forms.

There is a vast literature on Hilbert mf, a little less on Bianchi.
If I may, you can look at the last chapter of my recent book with Fredrik Str\"omberg published by the AMS.